# drupal multisite

Tags: 7, theming, database, search, multi-sites

I already have a Drupal 7 website. I want to extend it to a second one. The first one is stored in a subfolder. I want to create a second subfolder to store the second one. At the base I will have an intro
page which will redirect to either the 1st or the 2nd one. I do not care for different domain names. I just want different content (different menus) and slightly different template. Also same users same admin. But I would like the search to be site related.

What is the easiest way to do this? Should I create a 2nd databale or use the Domain Access module? If I create a 2nd database how can I have shared logged users? If I have the same database how will the admin
be able to update each one separately (assign nodes to sitesa) and should I override the search module to only query site-related content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to setup a drupal multisite.

Domain Access works well as its one code base, one database and one user base. Content can also be shared easily between each of the sites.

Domain Access is only one of the easiest to deploy and create any number of sub sites. Any node can be associated with as many sites as you have and node edits apply across all domains. You can also set different themes for each site to give them a different look and feel.

However in your case as previous poster pointed out it might be an overkill.

I would suggest you use Context module (https://drupal.org/project/context) to have ability to load different content and menu's. This would give you different "landing pages" while keeping single instance of Drupal and single user base.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need multisite for you needs. In fact it may work against you.

Cant you have

```
 / = intro page
 /sitea/ = menu and templates for site a
 /siteb/ = menu and templates for site b
```

Comment: Yes but I want users to be common between them. I don't want a user to have to register twice. This could mean same database or updating the users table in 2 databases. However it wouldn't make sense for the search to return results from both sites. So what I want is common database for users but different for content maybe. Maybe there is a single sign in solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Single Sign-On](http://drupal.org/project/sso) module. I am not sure about the name, but it shares user table across Multiple sites.

> Single Sign-On (SSO) means that if you are logged onto the master
>   site, you will automatically be logged into any slave site that you
>   visit.